# How to use image on label depending on data?

Tags: highcharts

I have a polar chart and I want to use little icon on label. The icon to use depend on data. 
So I add an url with the icon in the data of the series but I cannot take it in the xAxis.

```
xAxis: {
   labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<image src='+this.point.icon+'/>';
  },
    useHTML: true
}
    },

yAxis: {
    max: 7,
    tickInterval : 1

},

 plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    },
    series: {
       stacking : "normal"
    }
},


series: [{
  name : 'Serie A',
  color : "#76DFE4",
  data : [
    {name : "Data 1", y : 3, icon : "https://via.placeholder.com/15" },
    {name : "Data 2", y : 3, icon : "https://via.placeholder.com/15" },
    {name : "Data 3", y : 2, icon : "https://via.placeholder.com/15" }
  ],


},{
  name: 'Serie B',
  color : "#37C0F7",
  data: [
{name : "Data 1", y : 1, icon : "https://via.placeholder.com/15" },
    {name : "Data 2", y : 2, icon : "https://via.placeholder.com/15" },
    {name : "Data 3", y : 3, icon : "https://via.placeholder.com/15" }

  ]
```

Please see the JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/gpn6mLah/9/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the `icon` property in this way:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            var point = this.chart.series[0].userOptions.data[this.pos];
            if (point) {
                return '<image src=' + point.icon + '/>';
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vdqk45no/

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I need. But how can I know the way to access the point ? I searched in the documentation but I didn't find userOptions. What is it?

Comment: Hello @melanied, You can use some browser developer tools and log `this` in the function. The `userOptions` property is internal and it contains options set by a user.